# How can varchar containing integer work in calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server

How come string can contain integer. Even if I assume string storing numeric values as string, but even i can use in it calculation and getting the result as well. Just to try I wrote 5 in inverted commas and still calculation works fine. Not sure how?

```
declare @x varchar(20)
declare @y int
select @x='5'
select @y=6
select @x+@y
```

Comment: Because [datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). But you shouldn't do this - implicit conversion is generally a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

A `varchar` can contain *any* character from the collations codepage you are using. For the purposes of this answer, I'm going to assume you're using something like the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (which doesn't have any "international" characters, like Kanji, Hiragana, etc).

You first declare the variable `@x` as a `varchar(20)` and put the **`varchar`** value `'5'` in it. This is **not** an `int`, it's a `varchar`. This is an important distinction as a `varchar` and a numerical data type (like an `int`) behave very differently. For example `'10'` has a **lower** value than `'2'`, where as the opposite is true for `10` and `2`. (This is one reason why using the **correct** data type is always important.)

Then the second variable you have is `@y`, which is an `int` and has the value `6`.

Then you have your expression `SELECT @x+@y;`. This has 2 parts to it. Firstly, as you have 2 datatypes, [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) comes into play. `int` has a higher precedence than a `varchar`, and so `@x` is *implicitly* converted to an `int`. Then the expression is calculated, uses `+` as an addition operator (not a concatenation operator). Therefore the expression is effectively derived like this:

```
@x + @y = '5' + 6 = CONVERT(int,'5') + 6 = 5 + 6 = 11
```

> SQL Server uses the following precedence order for data types:
>
> 1. user-defined data types (highest)
> 2. sql_variant
> 3. xml
> 4. datetimeoffset
> 5. datetime2
> 6. datetime
> 7. smalldatetime
> 8. date
> 9. time
> 10. float
> 11. real
> 12. decimal
> 13. money
> 14. smallmoney
> 15. bigint
> 16. int
> 17. smallint
> 18. tinyint
> 19. bit
> 20. ntext
> 21. text
> 22. image
> 23. timestamp
> 24. uniqueidentifier
> 25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> 26. nchar
> 27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
> 28. char
> 29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
> 30. binary (lowest)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server -- and all other databases -- convert values among types when the need arises.

In this case, you have `+` which can be either string concatenation or number addition.  Because one argument is an integer, it is interpreted as addition, and SQL Server attempts to convert the string to a number.

If the string cannot be converted, then you will get an error.

I would advise you to do your best to avoid such implicit conversions.  Use the correct type when defining values.  If you need to store other types in a string, use `cast()`/`convert()` . . . or better yet, `try_cast()`/`try_convert()`:

```
try_convert(int, @x) + @y
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the point. but just wondering why this conversion don't happen in below case.  select (11/3) . This gives result as 3 instead of 3.66

Comment: `3.66` is a `decimal` @DevdasVivek . Neither `11` or `3` are a `decimal`, they are an `int`; so an `int` is returned.

Comment: @DevdasVivek . . . That is a different issue.  SQL Server does integer division, so 11/3 is returned as an integer value (using truncation rather than round).